# Chrome: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getCurrent' of undefined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Whatever I'm doing in chrome, I always see this message in the console.

It's coming from a file called 'popup.js'.

If I click on the name of that file as it shows in the console, I can see that the problem function is chrome.windows.getCurrent

The file in which it is defined attributes authorship to "The Chromium Authors"

What's going on here?

Can I eliminate this error without doing anything that will cause problems when I'm debugging my own javascripts?

Comment: Maybe you have a faulty plugin installed. Solution: Disable the plugin. FYI, I don't see such error in my browser. IMO this is not really a suitable question for SO.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it caused by one of your chrome plugins I guess